# IE Scrollbar issues when using Windows.load function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I used jquery to create dynamic textboxes on my website.
The code I uSed is as follows:

```
function RecreateDynamicTextboxes()
 {    var values = eval('<%=Values%>');   
 if (values != null) {      
  var html = "";   
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
 {    html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";    }        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;    }
}window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
```

This code causes issues with my scrollbar in internet explorer.The scrool bar just vanishes.
If I comment the windows.load function the scollbar works, but them as expected my code doesnt work.
How can I resolve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see one jQuery line in your code, you are using just plain JS.

But if you are using jQuery, means if you implemented it in your html, then you could use it:

```
function RecreateDynamicTextboxes()
    {
        var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
        if (values != null) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
            }
            $("#TextBoxContainer").html(html); 
        }
    }
    //Wait for DOM 
    $(document).ready(RecreateDynamicTextboxes);
```

or if you have to wait also for images to load

```
 $(document).load(RecreateDynamicTextboxes);
```

Hope it helps...